# Find a student with select grades

Tags: microsoft-access

I have just made an Access 2010 database for analyzing students’ grades in an exam. I was able to get grades for all students right. There are six subjects. What I want to do now is find who got A grade in any five out of six. That is, who missed full A grade by just one subject.

Right now I have the students’ grades in a tabular format. The students’ names, followed by their grades in all six subjects in the next six columns. Like this:

```
               ENG    LANGUAGE      PHY     CHE     BIO      MATH
ANN            A+      A+           C       A+      A+       A+

JOHN           B+       C           A       A+      B        C+
```

To find those who got A+ in all subjects I added A+ as the criteria in the query. But how do we find those who got A+ in ANY five subjects?

Can we add an expression to the query, or can we use a vba code? Could you please help me with it?I just couldn't find a way to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your database schema is poorly designed.  With a properly normalized schema this could be very easy.

Comment: Write an SQL query that uses the OR command.select Student from Table1 where eng=A+ or Language=A+...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database schema is poorly designed.  With a properly normalized schema you will get the results with a simple query.  This really probably should probably have 4 separate tables, but let me show you how to do this with two and a simple sql query.

One table will hold scores, and one table will hold our values.

```
ScoreValues
-----------
ID | Value
A+ | 4.3
A | 4.0
B | 3.0
C+ | 2.3
C | 2.0
D | 1.0

Scores
------
StudentID | Subject | Score
ANN | ENG | A+
ANN | LANGUAGE | A+
ANN | PHY | C
ANN | CHE | A+
ANN | BIO | A+
ANN | MATH | A+
JOHN | ENG | B+
JOHN | LANGUAGE | C
JOHN | PHY | A
JOHN | CHE | A+
JOHN | BIO | B
JOHN | MATH | C+

select Count(Subject) as AplusGradeCount, Student
from Scores,ScoreValues 
where Scores.Score=ScoreValues.Value and
      ScoreValues.Value > 4.0
Group By Student

QueryResults
------------
AplusGradeCount | Student
5 | ANN
1 | JOHN
```

Anyway, I strongly suggest you spend time learning about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  A properly normalized database will making querying the data far easier.

Comment: Cound you expand on the 4 tables solution? Could be quite useful to know the reasoning... thank you :)

Comment: @BigChris I would use a structure like this.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Cqh.png You want to do this because a student name might change in the future, or you might have multiple students with the same name.  You don't want to have to mass-update your scores table when a student name changes, you just want to update the Student table.  Likewise, the value of your Subjects might change, or you might add more.  You want to be able to change those without mass updating the scores table.